# How to expand elements with ajax using PHP Simple HTML DOM parser?

Tags: ajax, parsing

I use Google Chrome code inspect utility at the page  http://7pay.in/to_phone?phone=9101235577  when I scroll down to Bitcoin icon, something happening in ajax: I don't know how ajax works at all, but I really want to parse the Bitcoin address which is not represented as HTML code when you fetch the link given above, until you press Bitcoin button (Its not represented when I curl or wget the page)

Could you please give me a hint on how to work with that kind of ajax elements. I understand logically that by default some parts of page are hidden by Javascript, but I can't quite understand what I should do in order to work with it using PHP Simple DOM parser.

Comment: Where's your code ?Where's your code ?

Comment: Nothing special with my code, all I am successfully able to parse a lots of things with code constructions like foreach($html->find('div#foot') as $e) after simple dom html parser is initiated.

The question is how to force such constructions to "simulate" or find elements hidden by ajax in the page mentioned above